# iOS Swift Segmented control with container view for switching - views are not loading first time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I've followed this tut https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/ to create a segmented controller with two container views.

My problem is that the when app is launched first view is not shown. Clicking on second segment also doesn't do anything.

Only after third clicks and onwards these views are loaded.

It's strange as I've downloaded the code in tut and it works perfectly fine but it doesn't work when I create my own project and follow exactly same steps as shown in above tut.

Can anyone point me what I might be missing?

See the attached screenshot. When I run the app First segment is the default segment but in the view below it loads second segment.

Next when I click in Second it doesn't do anything.

Only after third click and onwards it loads correct segments.

[image]

Comment: My be you not write code for initial time which you done on button click, you code if right but you need to do code which you write to hide second view in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try added this code after method viewDidLoad, for show animation after app loaded.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.containerViewA.alpha = 1
            self.containerViewB.alpha = 0
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I still want to know why it works perfectly in the tutorial code and why not for me, any idea?

Comment: @Matt , do you have a project with only one view controller? Are you using a present for this controller or pushViewController? I do not know, need to review your project. You can send your archive to me and I will review your project for you.

Comment: That tutorial in example has it's own code available at: https://github.com/woelmer/EasyWayToSwitchContainerViews If you download and run it then you will see that it automatically works fine without adding any explicit code to set the default selected segment. Give it a try.

Comment: @Matt yes, I tried it. But project which I downloaded from url doesn’t work for me, I deleted action for segment and added again, after it started to work well. You can remove sequence and add again and checking parameters on storyboard for viewController. If you send me your code, I can to see if your app working and found problem.